# Angular 7, how to change "change detection strategy" to onpush for all components?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I want to change the `"default"` change detection strategy for all components in angular 7 app, and use `"onpush"` instead.

What should I do?

My solution is to go in every component and write this code:

```
@Component({
   ...,
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Is it a  right way when you want to change `changedetection` strategy for entire application, or is there any other (better way) way?